# <a> tag only execute one of two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, local-storage

So I am trying to make an summary page from a cart page. When I press CHECK OUT, we write to the tbody in another html document and empty the cart.

Problem is: When clicking the component which is an  tag(click event added) it will not write to the the selected tbody. However it will only empty the cart.

If I call the method that writes to the table instead of clicking the button, then everything shows up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to JavaScript & JQuery.

## JS FILE

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


  fetch("shoes.json")
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => {
    let shoes = data.shoes;
    loadAllFunctions(shoes);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

  function loadAllFunctions(shoes) { 
    let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.products || "[]");

    updateItemCount();
    loadCart();
    showOrHideButtons();

    // LADDAR UPP CART SIDAN MED ALLA PRODUKTER MED EN TABELL
    function loadCart() {
      let total = 0;
      let cartArea = $(".cart-area");
      let tableText = "<table id='soc' class='table mt-5'><thead class='thead-dark'><tr>" +
      "<th scope='col'>Article</th><th scope='col'></th><th scope='col'>Quantity</th><th scope='col'>Price</th><th scope='col'>Remove</th>" +
      "</tr></thead><tbody>";
      if(products.length != 0) {

        products.forEach(shoe => {
          let shoeTotal = (shoe.price * shoe.quantity);
          tableText += "<tr><td>" + "<img src=" + shoe.image + "></td>" +
          "<td class='font-weight-bold'><div class='mt-5'>" + shoe.name + "</div></td><td><div class='mt-5'>" + "<input class='cart-input' id=" + shoe.id + " type='number' min=0 value='" + shoe.quantity + "'></div>" + "</td>" +
          "<td class='font-weight-bold'><div id='" + shoe.id + "' class='price mt-5'>kr " + shoeTotal + "</div></td><td><button id='" + shoe.id + "' class='delete ml-3 mt-5'>X</button></td></tr>";
          total += shoeTotal;
        });

        tableText += "</tbody></table><hr><h4 id='total-amount' class='text-dark mb-5'><b>Total Amount:</b> kr " + total + "</h4>";
        cartArea.html(tableText);
      }
      else {
        cartArea.html("<h3 class='m-5'>There are no items in your cart.</h3><a id='continue-btn' class='ml-5' href='shopping.html'>CONTINUE SHOPPING</a>");
      }
      let deleteButton = $(".delete"); 
      deleteButton.click(function() {
        let clickedDeleteID = $(this).attr("id");

        products = removeShoe(clickedDeleteID);
        localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
        showOrHideButtons();
        loadCart();
        updateItemCount();
      });

      let cartInput = $(".cart-input");

      cartInput.change(updateShoeQuantity);
      //
      function updateShoeQuantity() {
        let totalAmount = $("#total-amount");
        let totalText = 0;
        let qtyInput = $(this); 
        let tempID = qtyInput.attr("id");
        let qtyValue = parseInt(qtyInput.val());
        let shoetotalPrice = $("#" + tempID + ".price");  // hämtar innehållet i denna
        if(qtyValue < 0) {
          qtyValue = 0;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
          const shoe = products[i];

          if(shoe.id == tempID) {
            if(qtyValue != 0) {
              shoe.quantity = qtyValue;
              shoetotalPrice.html("kr " + (shoe.price * shoe.quantity))
              break;
            }
            else {
              products = removeShoe(shoe.id);
              loadCart();
              break;
            }
          } 
        }
        localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
        updateItemCount();
        showOrHideButtons();
        for (let j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {
          const shoe = products[j];
          totalText += (shoe.price * shoe.quantity);
        }
        totalAmount.html("<b>Total Amount:</b> kr " + totalText);
      }
    }

    function removeShoe(ID) {
      let tempProducts = [];
      products.forEach(shoe => {
        if(shoe.id != ID) {
          tempProducts.push(shoe);
        }
      });
      return tempProducts;
    }

    // UPPDATERAR ANTAL SKOR I KART KNAPPEN I NAVBAR
    function updateItemCount() {
      let cart = $(".cart-btn");
      cart.html("");
      let totalItems = 0;
      products.forEach(shoe => {
        totalItems += shoe.quantity;
      });

      if(totalItems == 1) {
        cart.html(totalItems + " ITEM <img src='images/shoppingBag2.png' alt='cart'>");
      }
      else {
        cart.html(totalItems + " ITEMS <img src='images/shoppingBag2.png' alt='cart'>");
      }
    }



    function addToCart(cBtn) {
      let clickedButton = $(cBtn); 
      let buttonID = clickedButton.attr("id");
      let thisInput = $("#" + clickedButton.attr("id") + ".input-form").children("input");
      let newShoe = {
        id: buttonID,
        image: shoes[buttonID].image,
        name: shoes[buttonID].name,
        price: shoes[buttonID].price,
        quantity: parseInt(thisInput.val())
      };       

      if (products.length != 0) {
        let isExists = products.some(shoe => shoe.name === newShoe.name);
        if (!isExists) { 
          products.push(newShoe);
        } else {
          products = products.map(shoe => {
            if (shoe.name == newShoe.name && !isNaN(newShoe.quantity)) {
              shoe.quantity += newShoe.quantity;
              return shoe;
            }
            return shoe;
          });
        }
        localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
      } else {
        products.push(newShoe);
        localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
      }
      updateItemCount();
      loadCart();
    }

    let $table = $(".shoe-table");
    let rows = [1, 2, 3];
    let shoeCard = "";
    let counter = 0;
    rows.forEach(row => {
      shoeCard += "<tr>";
      for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        shoeCard +=
        "<td class='card text-center'>" +
        "<img class='card-img-top' src=" +
        shoes[counter].image +
        " alt='Card image cap'>" +
        "<h5 class='card-title'>" +
        shoes[counter].name +
        "</h5>" +
        "<p class='card-text'>kr " +
        shoes[counter].price +
        "</p>" +
        "<button id=" +
        counter +
        " class='orderNow btn btn-outline-dark'>ORDER NOW</button>" +
        "<div id=" +
        counter +
        " class='input-form'><input class='qty-chooser' type='number' placeholder='Choose quantity' min=0 max=10>" +
          "<button class='btn-add-to-cart' disabled='disabled'>ADD TO CART</button>" +
          "</div>" +
          "</td>";
        counter++;
      }

      shoeCard += "</tr>";
    });

    $table.append(shoeCard);
    let $inputForm = $(".input-form");
    let $orderBtn = $(".orderNow");

    $inputForm.hide();

    let activeButton = -1;

    // Denna metod tittar om man redan har en aktiv beställning
    function isProductActive() {
      let btnID = $(this).attr("id");
      if (activeButton == -1) {
        activeButton = btnID;
        toggleOrder($(this)); 
      } else if (btnID != activeButton) {
        toggleOrder($("#" + activeButton + ".orderNow"));
        toggleOrder($(this));
        activeButton = btnID;
      } else if (btnID == activeButton) {
        toggleOrder($(this));
        activeButton = -1;
      }
    }

    $orderBtn.click(isProductActive);

    function toggleOrder(buttonC) {
      console.log("INSIDE TOGGLE");
      let clickedBtn = $(buttonC);
      let thisInputForm = $("#" + clickedBtn.attr("id") + ".input-form");

      let inputBtn = thisInputForm.children("button");
      let inputIn = thisInputForm.children("input");

      // RESETTAR ELEMENT I .input-form
      function resetInputForm() {
        inputBtn.css("background", "");
        inputBtn.css("color", "");
        inputBtn.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        inputIn.val(null);
      }

      // DENNA KNAPP ÄR EN KNAPP MED ETT ANROP TILL ADDTOCART OCH RESETAR INPUTFORM
      inputBtn.click(function() {

        addToCart(clickedBtn);
        thisInputForm.hide("slow");
        clickedBtn.text("ORDER NOW");
        clickedBtn.css("background", "");
        resetInputForm();
        activeButton = -1;
      });
      // BEROENDE PÅ QUANTITY REAGERAR ADD TO CART KNAPPEN
      inputIn.change(function() {
        let qty = inputIn.val();

        if (qty >= 1 && qty <= 10) {
          inputBtn.removeAttr("disabled");
          inputBtn.css("background", "rgb(15, 163, 10)");
          inputBtn.css("color", "white");
        } else {
          resetInputForm();
        }
      });

      // KONTROLLERAR ORDER NOW KNAPPEN
      if (clickedBtn.text() == "CANCEL") {
        thisInputForm.hide("slow");
        clickedBtn.text("ORDER NOW");
        clickedBtn.css("background", "");
        resetInputForm();
      } else {
        thisInputForm.show("slow");
        clickedBtn.text("CANCEL");
        clickedBtn.css("background", "red");
        resetInputForm();
      }
    }

    function showOrHideButtons() {
      let bArea = $("#button-area");
      if(products.length == 0) {
        bArea.hide()
      }
      else {
        bArea.show();
      }
    }

    let emptyButton = $(".empty-button");

    emptyButton.click(emptyCart);
```

## RELEVANT CODE

```
    function emptyCart() {
      products = [];
      localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));
      showOrHideButtons();
      loadCart();
      updateItemCount();
    }

    $(".make-order").click(loadOrderSummary);

    function loadOrderSummary() {
      let shoeTbody = $(".shoe-data");
      let summaryText = "";
      products.forEach(shoe => {
        let sum = (shoe.quantity * shoe.price);
        summaryText += "<tr><td>" + shoe.name + "</td>"+ 
        "<td>" + shoe.quantity + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + sum + "</td></tr>";   
      });
      shoeTbody.html(summaryText);
      emptyCart();
    }

  }

});
```

## HTML DOC

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Order Confirmation</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <button class="navbar-toggler mr-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
              <img class="img-fluid ml-5" src="images/WebShoelogo.png" alt="logo">
            </a>   
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About us</a>
                    </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="shopping.html">Shopping</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>     
              </div>

                <a class="cart-btn ml-auto" href="cart.html">
                  0 ITEMS
                  <img src="images/shoppingBag2.png" alt="cart">
              </a>
              </nav>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center"><h1 class="mt-5">Your order has been successfully placed!</h1>
                <h3 class="mb-5">You will have your order within 3 - 7 business days!</h3>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">

            </div>
            <div class="col-8 mt-5 mb-5">
                   <table class="Order-summary table table-dark table-hover m-auto">
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                               <th class="thHeader">
                                   Order Summary
                               </th>                            
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <th>Article</th>
                               <th>Quantity</th>
                               <th>Sum</th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody class="shoe-data">
                           <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                   <a id="continue-btn" class="mt-5" href="shopping.html">CONTINUE SHOPPING</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h1 class="hideHeader">IOjdsodfjsdiofjoisjdfoij</h1>
                <h1 class="hideHeader">IOjdsodfjsdiofjoisjdfoij</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">  
            <br><br>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-1"></div>
              <div class="col-10">
                <table class="table footer-table m-auto">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="heading">
                        HELP CENTER
                      </th>
                      <th class="heading">
                        ABOUT US
                      </th>
                      <th class="heading">
                        GIFT CARDS AND OTHER
                      </th>
                      <th class="heading">
                        CONNECT WITH US
                      </th>
                      <th>
                        PAYMENT METHODS
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        FAQs <br>
                        Sizing Guide <br>
                        Contact Us <br>
                        30 Day Trial <br>
                        Exchange & Returns
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        TRUE story <br>
                        Materials Matter <br>
                        Business Model <br>
                        Wayfarers Club
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        Wood Gift Cards (physical) <br>
                        E-Gift Certficates (digital) <br>
                        Sitemap
                      </td>
                      <td class="connect">
                        <a href="#">
                          <img src="images/instagram.png" alt="instagram">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                          <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook">
                        </a> <br>
                        <a href="#">
                          <img src="images/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                          <img src="images/twitter.png" alt="twitter">
                        </a>
                      </td>
                      <td class="payment">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="images/americanex.png" alt="AE">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="images/visa.png" alt="visa"><br>
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="images/mastercard.png" alt="MC">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="images/paypal.png" alt="PP">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>

                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-2">
                    <img class="img-fluid ml-5" src="images/WebShoelogo.png" alt="logo">

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6">

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4">
                    <p class="ml-5">&copy; 2020 WebShoe</p>
                    <a class="privacy ml-3" href="">PRIVACY POLICY</a>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-1"></div>
            </div>


          </div>


    </div>


    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="product.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does summaryText look like if you console.log it just before `shoeTbody.html(summaryText);` ?

Comment: As @WillJenkins said, please, show us console.logs of summaryText & shoeTbody variables. Even better, if you can share your html as well.

Comment: I see nowhere where you're setting localStorage to anything other than an empty array...

Comment: added more information for you guys too look at.

Answer (score 1):

That's Because it's not a best way to do it. You can just store the plain text and then append html tags after retrieving the data using conditional statements as you are doing already. If you still want to do it the same way you can encode your string into some other form like Base64 String or some other and store it and then decode it after retrieving. But this is very long process I would'nt recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Just write another js file that executes when the page loads. ;)

```
function loadOrderSummary() {
  let shoeTbody = $(".shoe-data");
  let summaryText = "";
  products.forEach(shoe => {
    let sum = (shoe.quantity * shoe.price);
    summaryText += "<tr><td>" + shoe.name + "</td>"+ 
    "<td>" + shoe.quantity + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + sum + "</td></tr>";   
  });
  shoeTbody.html(summaryText);
  localStorage.clear();
}

 loadOrderSummary();
```